# Apache-drill execute sum agregation on rdms server

Tags: oracle, sum, rdbms, apache-drill

Apache Drill, is looking to be an interesting integration option for some of the issues I am solving, but I have run into a snag, when using the RDBMS plugin (Oracle specifically) the aggregation and calculation of sum() appears to be happening on the client not as an SQL pass through to the underlying provider - this has a negative performance impact since you effectively pull the whole dataset over the wire.  Does anyone know how native SQL can be specified where it is run for providers that support it?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely an issue with the JDBC Storage plugin in Drill. In many cases Drill does not push down group by and order by to the underlying database. If you'd like this optimization to be added to Drill's planner please get in touch with us on the Drill mailing lists. http://drill.apache.org/mailinglists/